# What is the equivalent packages build-essential and linux-headers-<xxxx> in alpine?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, kernel-modules, alpine-linux, pkg

I want to build kernel modules in Alpine; I know how to do it in Ubuntu.
In Ubuntu, I used to install kernel headers by running:

```
apt install -y build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

What is the equivalent in Alpine?

I searched on the web and [Github user progrium wrote a comment](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/24#issuecomment-89771871) that the equivalent for `build-essential` is `build-base`, but what about the `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`build-base` is indeed the equivalent to `build-essential`.

The package providing the headers and scripts needed to build kernel modules is the `-dev` package matching your kernel package, *e.g.* [`linux-lts-dev`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/linux-lts-dev).